# Using Regex pattern to copy and rename Excel sheet using VBA

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I having trouble creating VBA to copy an existing sheet and rename the copy with a specific suffix.

The existing sheet is named with a variable prefix (a digit code) followed by a fix suffix.

The copied sheet should be renamed with the same prefix, followed by another fix suffix.

I would like to use regex to do so, but I cannot figure out how to specify the sheet names with regex. The pattern would simply be something like `[0-9]+` for the prefix.

The suffix are always the same.

> Example:
>   Existing sheet: 123_raw
>   New copied sheet: 123_analyzed

This is what I have so far and don't know how to go on:

```
Dim objRegex As Object
Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With objRegex
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "[0-9]+"
```

It should look something similar to this I guess:

```
Sheets("regex pattern + [suffix]").Select
Sheets("regex pattern + [suffix]").Copy After:=Sheets(3)
Sheets("regex pattern + [suffix] (2)").Select
Sheets("regex pattern + [suffix] (2)").Name = "regex pattern + [new suffix]"
```

But I have no idea on how to actually code it.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried `replace`?

Comment: I just updated the question with some more specific information. Hope it's clear enough now. @Tom 
I now have posted the little code I have so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Assuming your Sheet names are 123_raw 456_raw Or something **`[3 digits_words]`** so your Pattern will be **`Pattern = "([0-9]{3}\_)"`**  **https://regex101.com/r/Iu6nxn/1***

---

> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> ***`([0-9]{3}\_)`** Match a single character present in the list below
>
> **`0-9`** a single character in the range between `0` and `9` 
>
> **`{3}`** Quantifier — Matches exactly 3 times
>
> **`\_`** matches the character `_` literally (case sensitive)*

---

*VBA Code Example as simple as it can be - Here we are searching for the sheet name **`123_`** or **`[3 digits_words]`** Copy and rename to **`3 digits_analyzed`***

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    Dim RegExp As Object
    Dim Matches As Variant
    Dim Pattern As String
    Dim NewName As String
    Dim Sht As Worksheet
        
    Set RegExp = CreateObject("VbScript.RegExp")

    For Each Sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Pattern = "([0-9]{3}\_)" ' Sheet name 123_
    
        With RegExp
            .Global = False
            .Pattern = Pattern
            .IgnoreCase = True
             Set Matches = .Execute(Sht.Name)
        End With

        If Matches.Count > 0 Then
            Debug.Print Matches(0) ' Print on Immediate Win
            
            NewName = Matches(0) & "analyzed" ' New sheet name
            Sht.Copy After:=Sheets(3) ' Copy Sheet
            ActiveSheet.Name = NewName ' Rename sheet with new name
            
        End If
    Next
    
    Set RegExp = Nothing
    Set Matches = Nothing
    Set Sht = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (where *_new* replaces the prior suffix)

```
Sub B()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim objRegex As Object

Set ws = Sheets(1)
Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

With objRegex
    .Pattern = "([0-9]+)_[a-z]+"
    If .test(ws.Name) Then
        ws.Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        ActiveSheet.Name = .Replace(ws.Name, "$1_new")
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this out and it didn't give any errors. However, I also didn't see any new sheet being added. There's probably something missing. It was, however, helpful for other regards. Thanks a lot for the input! Much appreciated!